# eclipse serializable members validation

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, serializable

When I define a Java class to be Serializable, Eclipse does not warn me that Some of the members are not Serializable, which may cause the application to fail serializing @ runtime.

I couldn't find any setting to enable the member validation.

Any idea on how to validate that members of a Serializable class are also Serializable?

Thanks

Comment: I'm talking about mere warning - no need to make it an error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no one comes up with a way to do this in eclipse directly, I would reccomend the FindBugs plug-in it has a rule `SerializableIdiom` which I believe should highlight the issue you are worried about.

I can add more details on the rule if required. They are  pain to format for display in here though so I gave up adding them to the original answer

Answer (score 0):

It is legal to have a reference to a type that is not Serializable which ends up pointing at a serializable object at runtime:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
```

public class Test implements Serializable {

```
private Object data;

public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

if you latter write something like:

```
    Test t1 = new Test();
    Test t2 = new Test();
```

```
t1.setData("Serializable");
t2.setData(new Object());
```

you will have no problems serializing t1 but will blow up on t2.

Comment: That is why the type of data should probably be Serializable and NOT Object.Tthis way, you can't set just any object and won't fail at runtime

Comment: Well, if you are willing to enforce all setters to accept only Serializable parameters ( e.g. public void setData(Serializable data) {...} ) then you do not have the original problem because all non Serializable assignments will be caught at compile time.

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to enforce, but the compiler does NOT shout that a member of a serializable is serializable

Comment: If you think about the example I provided, you will see that the compiler has no way of enforcing this as this is resolved at runtime and not compile time.